# Механизм пакетного обновления моего приложения

Tags: c#, c++

Добрый день!

Есть клиент-серверное ПО, которое периодически обновляется (выходят новые версии).
Хочется, чтобы у пользователей происходило автоматическое обновление клиентской части (Windows). Сервер под Linux.

Думаю можно для этого использовать некую систему управления пакетами, типа APT, серверная часть которой будет уже готовой.
При запуске моего ПО у клиента должна проходить проверка, не появилось ли обновление программы в этой системе управления пакетами. Если появилось - скачиваются пакеты обновлений, распаковываются, моё ПО обновляется.
При этом может потребоваться добавлять, обновлять и удалять файлы.

Существует ли готовое или полу-готовое решение для такой задачи?

Comment: Также рассматриваю как вариант использование систем контроля версий (svn, hg, git), заточенных на бинарные файлы (плагины типа bigfiles). Но мне кажется, что это уже слишком избыточно для моей задачи.

Comment: Может быть, вам подойдёт [`ClickOnce`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce).

Comment: Спасибо за совет!
Посмотрел что умеет делать ClickOnce.

Как понял, это довольно узкоспециализированное решение, которое может быть использовано с .NET приложениями. А мне хотелось бы использовать свой механизм обновления для любых приложений, не только .NET.
И обновление хотелось бы проводить явно для пользователя, интерактивно, из своей программы-апдейтера с красивым GUI.

Даже так - использовать один такой апдейтер для обновления сразу нескольких программ на компьютере пользователя. Сам апдейтер является одновременно и точкой входа в программы, обновляет и запускает их. Или просто запускае

Comment: Может тогда свой гуй + локальный репозиторий http://chocolatey.org/ ?